# JQuery acting odd in IE when I'm NOT in compatibility mode

Tags: javascript, jquery

this is odd and I'm not sure why it is happening.  I have this piece of code:

```
for(var x=0; x<8; x++){
  var y = $('#divID'+x).html();
  console.log(y);
}
```

When I am IN IE9 compatibility mode it works just fine.  However, when I turn OFF IE9 compatibility mode it doesn't work, nothing appears in the console or on my page.  Now here is the odd thing, When I using this snippet of code instead, it works just fine.

```
for(var x=0; x<8; x++){
  var y = document.getElementById('divID'+x).innerHTML;
  console.log(y);
}
```

Is there something I am missing?  Please help and thank you in advance.

Comment: What version of JQuery? Can you provide a JS Fiddle?

Comment: Ok, a little more research.  Please don't beat me up for this, I have no choice and have to go about it this way....The code is being called in a frame.  I have jQuery included at the top and make a call by reference by using the following: var $ = function(a){return top.$(a, this.document);} to reference jQuery in the frame from the top.  I'm noticing a lot of the jQuery isn't working.

Comment: When I include jQuery direct into the frame everything works fine.  so something is up with the var $ = function(a){return top.$(a, this.document);} call.  Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: @Tim S, sorry, I don't think JSFiddle can handle this one as I need to have multiple HTML for the frames to setup my example.

Comment: This is not an iframe this is a regular set of frames.

Comment: Eew, `FRAME`s. Well, I'm out.

Answer (score 1):

IE doesn't support the console object till IE11...bummer, huh? It will break your js.
Debug in Chrome...just use the IE browser as a final check after your js checks out in Chrome...just be sure to remove or comment your console.log/debug lines.

Comment: He uses `console` in both examples.  It's getting the element that's different between the two.

Comment: Chrome works perfectly, so does Firefox and Safari.  It's just IE when it's NOT in compatibility mode that has the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You need to consider these points:

1. Firstly check if some of your code is incorrect in your `$(document).ready()`.
2. If that all looks fine reload your page and hit F12 click the script tab then click start debugging and it will reload the page and halt it with a break point at your error in JavaScript..

**jQuery** does work in IE9 RC.

However, if you are doing something that **IE** doesnot support near the top of your `$(document).ready()` it could be preventing the rest of the page from loading.

Also http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.1rc1.js, this should help you.

Comment: Ok, a little more research. Please don't beat me up for this, I have no choice and have to go about it this way....The code is being called in a frame. I have jQuery included at the top and make a call by reference by using the following: var $ = function(a){return top.$(a, this.document);} to reference jQuery in the frame from the top. I'm noticing a lot of the jQuery isn't working.